# Is it possible to combine Data Table with a grid in an MVC View?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to display data from a database table into a 2x3 grid. Which after will be paginated so you can swipe to all data without having to list everything from top to bottom. What I was wondering is, is this possible to perform with data table and a grid in a cshtml view? Below is the mock-up.

This is what I currently have and now everything is just displayed underneath eachother. I'd like to change this.

View

```
@model List<Models.Kolom>
@{
    Layout = "";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>          
                <th>                 
                </th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
flex-container {
    display: flex;
    /*Generates a flexbox layout with default flex direction as row */
    width: 100%;
    /* Not really required */
    align-items: center;
    /*Aligns contents vertically */
    justify-content: center;
    /*Aligns contents horizontally */
    text-align: center;
    /*Aligns further text in the center */
}

.item {
    background-color: #1A1919;
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```

```
 @{ int numberOfRenderedCells = 0; }

                @while (numberOfRenderedCells < Model.Count)
                {
                    <div class="flex-container">

                        @for (var j = 0; j < numberOfCols; j++)
                        {
                            if (numberOfRenderedCells < Model.Count)
                            {
                                var item = Model.ElementAt(numberOfRenderedCells);
                                <div class="item">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Naam)
                                </div>
                            }

                            numberOfRenderedCells++;
                        }
                    </div>
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to just use a table with multiple columns per row.

```
@{ const int NumberOfColsToRender = 3; /* desired number of table columns */ }

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @* Render desired number of header columns per row *@
            @for (var i = 0; i < NumberOfColsToRender; i++) {
                <th></th> 
            }                   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{ int totalRenderedCells = 0; }
        @* render rows as long as we have items *@
        @while (totalRenderedCells < Model.Length) {
            <tr>
                @* Render desired number of data cells per row *@
                @for (var j = 0; j < NumberOfColsToRender; j++) {
                    if (totalRenderedCells < Model.Length) {
                        var item = Model.ElementAt(totalRenderedCells);
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                    }
                    else {
                        @* fill up rest of row with empty cells after we run out of items *@
                        <td></td>
                    }
                    totalRenderedCells++;
                 }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you sir this has helped. I have edited my post and added the grid I wish to add the table information into. Is it possible to combine the data table and the grid and how can I insert divs into the data table html?

Comment: Hm I guess you can just replace the `<tr>` with `<div class="flex-container">` and the `<td>` with `<div class="item">` in the code I gave above. No need for the `<table>`, `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags anymore.

Comment: It works now the way I wish to thank you so much! What I wonder is will the pagination limit the amount of grids or how can I keep it 3x3 on one page?Because now it goes beyond it

Comment: Can you set the number of items per page to 9 in the pager?

Comment: In what way would that be possible? I have heard of PaginatedList but I haven't implemented it yet. I haven't implemented a pager yet. Could you recommend a pager for me to implement?

Comment: The controller action called when clicking next/previous should get the desired page number as parameter (starting with 0 for the first page). Then return `items.Skip(desiredPageNumber*desiredItemsPerPage).Take(desiredItemsPerPage)` to the view.

Comment: Yes but before I can do that I need the implement the pager itself. Which pager do I need for this case?

Comment: Sorry I can't recommend a pager. We either use [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/) (but this would render a classic table with one row per item) or implement paging ourselves as described above.